# Detect DOM loading completion

Tags: reactjs, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm running react based single-page-app. Is there a way to detect when the DOM completed loading? is there any relevant event?
I managed to find LargestContentfulPaint but that doesn't seems to do the job (or is it and I'm using it all wrong?). Also I managed to find window.onpaint, but that API seems to be deprecated. Furthermore, I've also tried 'DOMContentLoaded', which for some reason doesn't yield anything...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't fire for you, it's likely at the moment that you ran that, the dom has already loaded. See [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

Comment: May I ask why you need to detect this in a React app? I wonder if there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: @StephenJennings I want to create visual regression tests with as minimal as possible generic wait times

Comment: @SimonCheng thanks, I'll try it. Can you please explain the logic why one should work and the other don't?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) which waits for resources to be loaded before being run.

Comment: Thanks, but window.onload seems to be a deprecated event (MDN website)

Comment: @BarakBensimhon I might be missing something, but nowhere I've looked do I see it being deprecated? The link I sent in my original comment it still says there is full support. Could you send me a link to where you saw this?

Comment: I can swear that last week it showed in the MDN's documentation last week and that it is deprecated (can't find it now also, they most have updated their documentation). Nevertheless, I've tried it and it didn't work as well :/
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Following going through many of the possible APIs and trying them out, I managed to find 'MutationObserver.observe()' API targeted to detect mutations in the document as (using MDN's documentation example):

```
// identify an element to observe
const elementToObserve = document;

// create a new instance of `MutationObserver` named `observer`,
// passing it a callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
console.log('callback that runs when observer is triggered');
});

// call `observe()` on that MutationObserver instance,
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elementToObserve, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

I'm not sure how it works, but it this event seems to track visual changes in my app pretty well. Hope it helps anyone other than me!